# change.js not changing the price on cart page shopify

Tags: shopify, shopify-template, shopify-api-node

I am trying to change the total price of product by ajax but its not changing here is my code.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/cart/change.js',
      data: { 

        id:28641310441556,
        total_price:900,

      },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function() {
      //do anything
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

Shopify Docs does not mention any price change option via [AJAX API](https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/development/getting-started/using-ajax-api#change-cart). According to Shopify Docs

> The /cart/update.js controller allows updates to several items at
>   once, including items that might not yet be in the cart (it will add
>   them), and it also allows updates to cart attributes and the cart
>   note.

If you want to change price via API, use [Shopify REST API](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/products).

If you want to offer discounts to customer, use [Discount Codes](https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/promoting-marketing/discount-codes).

Cart prices can be manipulated using [Shopify Scripts](https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/apps/apps-by-shopify/script-editor/examples) that are offered as a part of Shopify Plus Plan.